# Serving and embedding video in HTML?

Tags: html, apache, video

Say we have apache setup serving a basic HTML index.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, World!</p>

        <!-- INSERT HERE -->

        <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

We have a 5 min video clip we would like to embed on the web page.

I assume we place the video file next to the index.html in the /var/www and then insert some html on the page.

We would like a single frame of the video showing with a PLAY icon in the center, and when clicked we would like it to play inside its frame by default, but also have a full-screen button.  (Like an embedded YouTube video behaves)

Questions:

- Which video format should we encode the file in?
- What snippet of HTML should we replace "INSERT HERE" with?
- How is this problem usually solved?

If there are multiple solutions we would like the most compatible one in terms of browsers, operating systems and desktop/mobile?

Comment: Have you tried mediaelementjs.com, take a look for all solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to create a custom player.
you can build one using Flash or look for one, [here](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CHwQFjAF&url=http://www.communitymx.com/abstract.cfm?cid=4E1D8&ei=-7fZT66OKYbitQaQtZWtCA&usg=AFQjCNEk8kZzJ80g1RTwZnE4j_q8kz83UA&sig2=GVeCBwY2dQ5z2fnv30HkJg) is a link to a tutorial

And you can build or look for one in HTML 5, try [this](http://videojs.com/)

The video format depeneds on the player that runs it, so if you build a custom one you can decide yourself.